# flutter delete textformfield from listvew.builder with value

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a set of fields that I want to display
And a button that deletes his account
But I don't know how to make the delete button

[image]

Example when I try to delete the first field (1), it deletes it from the list, but deletes the third field instead of the first and keeps the old value
[image]

delete button code on press

```
onPressed: () {
  controller.texts.value.removeAt(i);
  controller.fieldsnumber.value = controller.texts.value.length;
       },
```

Textformfield code

```
TextFormField(
                                                    initialValue: controller.texts.value[i]['question'],
                                                    textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                                                    cursorColor: C1,
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                        fontSize: 18, color: C1),
                                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                                      filled: true,
                                                      fillColor: C2,
                                                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                                      ),
                                                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                          vertical: 25.0, horizontal: 20.0),
                                                      label: Row(
                                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                                        children: [
                                                          Text('نقطة التفتيش',textAlign: TextAlign.left,style : TextStyle(
                                                              color: C1, fontSize: 18)),
                                                        ],
                                                      ),
                                                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                                          color: C1, fontSize: 18),
                                                    ),
                                                    onSaved: (val) {
                                                      controller.texts.add(val);
                                                    },
                                                    validator: (val) {
                                                      if (val == null || val.isEmpty) {
                                                        return 'برجاء اكمال الحقل';
                                                      }
                                                    },
                                                  ),
```

but textformfield must get his initialValue from (text) list

Answer (score 0):

```
    In the ListView.builder you can get the index of the array. so you can easily get the onPressed delete icon index

By using that index you can get the id so you can pass it to server side to delete the object from the array.
    
    Example :
    
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index) {}
```